# How to shuffle a sequence of random numbers using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, random

Shuffling numbers works when data is in a sequence like 1,2,3,4,5 or 1,4,3,2,5.

When doing it in random form 1,2,4,6,7 it changes the sequence to 1,2,3,4,5 and gives random samples related to it. Here is a sample:

[image]

When I click on button1 it will randomize the sequence but change numbers to 1,2,3,4,5

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ShuffleArray(mArray() As Integer, iUbound As Integer)

    Dim iTop As Integer
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    Dim iSlot As Integer

    'first build it up
    ReDim mArray(iUbound)
    For iTemp = 1 To iUbound
        mArray(iTemp) = iTemp
    Next iTemp

    'now shuffle it
    For iTop = iUbound To 2 Step -1
        iTemp = mArray(iTop)
        iSlot = Int((iTop - 1) * Rnd + 1)
        mArray(iTop) = mArray(iSlot)
        mArray(iSlot) = iTemp
    Next iTop

End Sub

Sub RandomizeOrder()

    Dim iCities As Integer

    iCities = Sheet1.Range("X1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 2

    If iCities < 2 Or iCities > 100 Then MsgBox "Invalid number or cities", vbCritical: Exit Sub

    Dim mArray() As Integer
    Dim iA As Integer

    ShuffleArray mArray, iCities

    For iA = 1 To iCities
        Sheets("distances").Cells(iA + 2, 24).Value = mArray(iA) - 1
    Next iA

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to utilize the `Randomize` function in VBA too when you use [Rnd](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php)

```
'now shuffle it
For iTop = iUbound To 2 Step -1
    iTemp = mArray(iTop)
    Randomize ' <--- add this here
    iSlot = Int((iTop - 1) * Rnd + 1)
    mArray(iTop) = mArray(iSlot)
    mArray(iSlot) = iTemp
Next iTop
```

**Warning:** If you don't call the Randomize function before calling the Rnd function, the Rnd function may return the same random number value each time. And therefore, you may not get a truly random number.

Comment: Actually it changes numbers like if i use  3,5,6,7,9 it will change it to 1,2,3,4,5 this is an issue i want to sort..

Comment: I included a link to the `Rnd` function. You can read about how it works there.